# annotating co-first author in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, footnotes

Using either biblatex or bibtex, is there an accepted way of including a "co-first-author" footnote or annotation (for the purposes of a CV)?

Comment: Have you checked [biblatex-publist](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex-publist)? It's a style aimed at publication lists.

Comment: Thanks, @henrique.  Just checked.  It has some nice features for publication lists (which I will probably experiment with), but apparently has no features for co-first or -last author.

Comment: `publist`'s output is supposed to be "2012 (with Co-Author) *Title*...". How is it in your database? Are you using a custom `co-author` field instead of an `author` list?