# Equal contribution (co-first authors) in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

Is there a standard way of indicating co-first authorships in a BibTeX entry?

Equal-contribution is usually indicated by * (or some other symbol) next to the author names in the paper, but it is a rather [recent](http://blog.labguru.com/blog-labguru/on-being-equal-the-co-first-author-phenomenon) [phenomenon](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20933195) as I understand it.

I never actually saw it indicated in the reference sections when cited, but it is a valuable meta-data that might be useful for the future. Hence, I want to put it in the BibTeX meta data. I can imagine a new bibliography format showing co-first authors in the reference (but this is not likely to happen though).

Comment: How is it shown otherwise?

Comment: @jon I updated the question.

Comment: I'd be a bit wary about 'usually' here. In my area (chemistry) a star (or several stars) indicates the 'author to whom correspondence should be addressed', _i.e._ the lead author(s).

Comment: @JosephWright the symbol is of course flexible. footnote or side note is there for the interpretation of symbols.

Comment: `biblatex` offers the field `authortype`, one might be able to expand this to the host of possibilities one has with `editor[a|b|c]` and `editor[a|b|c]type`.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126864/annotating-co-first-author-in-bibliography

Comment: More importantly (in my field), shared first author papers are referred to differently: Instead of referencing a paper as “Foo et al.”, it should be referenced as “Foo, Bar et al.”.

Comment: I believe the bibliography formatting here answers the poster's question:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468623/indicating-joint-first-authorship-through-special-markup-in-biblatex-biber

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indicating joint first authorship through special markup in biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468623/indicating-joint-first-authorship-through-special-markup-in-biblatex-biber)

Comment: @helmingstay -- The question you cite uses `biblatex` for its answer.  The present question asks about `bibtex`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'standard' way of indicating this information in a `.bib` file. Moreover, it probably would be difficult to include it in the `author` field without breaking standard styles/sorting/... As such, if adding this information I would use a custom field (the BibTeX format allows for this as all non-recognised fields are ignored).

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution that may work for you: keep things together with parentheses.

```
author={{Foo, Bar} and third_author and fourth_author},
```

Comment: How do you propose to tell BibTeX about the first names of the authors?