# Showing all authors in bibtex publications

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, author-number

I am trying to include a publication and want to preserve the names of all authors (I do not want to cite a particular paper just mention it in a list of publications). [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133520/equal-contribution-co-first-authors-in-bibtex) question is similar but has not received a definite answer.

The content of the **.bib** file is:

```
@Misc{misc2,
  Title                    = {Title},

  Author                   = {A. Author1, B. Author2, C. Author3, D. Author4},
  Year                     = {2015}
}
```

but only the first author is shown.

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, load it with the `maxnames=99` option (that seems a sensible bound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bernard mentioned already, maxnames is a command which should solve your issue.
Here's a [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/biblatex-displaying-all-authors-of-multi-author-works-in-the-bibliography) with a full example.

NOTE: maxnames is the setting to change this behavior in your entire document whereas maxbibnames only refer to the bibliography.

Hope this helps.